# It is possible to view css transition frame by frame?

Tags: css, transition, frame

I have an html div, with css transition that moves it along the screen from left to right. I would like to be able to see the different frames, one by one, instead of 1 stopless smooth animation. It that possible?

Comment: I don't know what you really mean but only possible solution is increasing the time amount.

Comment: You can do a lot with [Chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/animations).

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS `steps()`. Hope it will help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    .move {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 20px;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
      background: #757575;
    }
    
    .move-1 {
      -webkit-animation: move-in-steps 8s steps(4) infinite;
      animation: move-in-steps 8s steps(4) infinite;
    }
    
    .move-2 {
      -webkit-animation: move-in-steps 8s infinite;
      animation: move-in-steps 8s infinite;
    }
    
    body {
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes move-in-steps {
      0% {
        left: 0;
      }
      100% {
        left: 100%;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes move-in-steps {
      0% {
        left: 0;
      }
      100% {
        left: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="move move-1">steps</div>
  <br>
  <div class="move move-2">no steps</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, you can use the Chrome DevTools Animation Inspector.

## How to Load Animation Drawer in Chrome

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/animations/

It is surprisingly hard to get to.

Open Dev Tools > Drawer 3 dot menu > Animations

[image]

Or you can Run a Command Show Animations

[image]

[image]

## How to view animation frame by frame

Once you have the Animation Inspector Open, trigger an animation. Then you can control the speed of playback, and use the playhead to scrub through the animation frame by frame like you editing a video.

[image]